# Enigmatic Boxes

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, computer-puzzle

```
     
    b25lIGVhc3k
    gb25lIHRvIH
    N0YXJ0Lg==
```

```
       
    cRIldI
    2oG0W/
    9aEIdI
    tWgHoQ
    Z5YRZ=
    XnmvX=
```

```
     
    k5WYoBSYgQmblxGIvRHI
    yVGd1BXbvNGIhBCa0l2d
    gQmbpZGIvRHI5NXYlByc
    pBSZu9GI0NXYsBycphGd
    cyBlYXN5IHRvIGZpbmQg
    d2l0aCBhIGNvbXB1dGVy
    IHRvIGxlbmQgYSBoYW5k
```

### Three locked boxes before you.

## Can you unravel their mysteries and reveal the greater truth?

Comment: There's a lot of shenanigans in here.

Answer (score 11):

user3608068 has the Base64 figured out:

1. > "one easy one to start."
2. > This reads top to bottom, and then left to right 
   > "something a bit tougher?!"
3. > This reads right to left and bottom to top, but the bottom three lines should be discarded and add the == 
   > "this last one is easy to find with a computer to lend a hand"

Since I happen to have a computer here, I went to the edit history and noticed that an image was removed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoEIP.png

This image when filled in with a colour shows:

> [image]

I then had to go back to figure out where the morse code was.  In the markdown for the post there is a section that looks like this:
[image]
The two dots are the "dash" and the single dots are the "dot" for the morse code.  The message is:

> GOOD WORK FINDING THIS, THERE'S ONE MORE THING TO BE FOUND.

I believe this corresponds to the image I found above.

The schmutz at the end of the image is actually a code.  The number of pixels in each shape is a letter:

> 1 12 1 13 14 23 15 18 4 7 15 15 4 2 5 25 5

Heeding the breaks as spaces and converting to letters of the alphabet yields:

> A LAMN WORD GOODBEYE

After I posted my original answer edit 3 was added to the original post.  It added a new block of code to the top of the post.  Using the tab character as the "dash" and the space character as the "dot" it is more code for:

> THE WISDOM YOU SEEK WAS YOURS ALL ALONG BUT ONLY IF YOU CAN EXPLAIN YOUR PATH HERE

I believe that I have adequately done this.

Comment: @Bob Is the mispelling of Base64 as Bas64 intentional?  I'm not sure if I've solved the problem or if there is more shenanigans in that itty bitty picture.

Comment: That which goes unseen and untouchable yet  still makes its presence felt holds the key.

Comment: @bob I won't be at a PC for a few days.  I saw all the white space before but couldn't make anything out of it.  I see you edited the post again.  I won't be able to see the markdown, so good luck to someone else!

Comment: @Bob Am I still missing something?

Comment: @Bob So was this the right answer, or is this question still outstanding?

Answer (score 6):

It's super easy when you know about

> [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

First box

> "one easy one to start."

Second box

> after transposing:
>
>  "something a bit tougher?!"

Third box

> after discarding 3 last lines (which are same as 3 first lines in reverse) and adding necessary ==
>
>  "this last one is easy to find with a computer to lend a hand"

Comment: These are not the truths you seek,

Answer (score 1):

Credit to LeppyR64 for cracking the code to reveal the letters

> A LAMN WORD GOODBEYE

However, I think this is an anagram which could lead to any of the following phrases (punctuations and spaces used where necessary).

> DAMN GOOD EYE, BRO LAW! (A compliment to a relative)
>  NAME A WORLD 'GOODBYE' (Highlighting the OP's frustration at "Hello World" programs)
>  GOOD NAMED LOWER BAY (A well known community called Lower Bay)
>  ONE BLOODY GEM AWARD (An honour in the serial killing fraternity)
>  OYE! A GODDAMN BLOWER! (An impatient farmhand in a tool shop)
>  OWE ME A BLOODY GRAND (An angry creditor)

Answer (score 1):

The morse code is within the first HTML comment in the markdown (not sure if this was added after Leppy's answer).

There are three different white-space characters. A dash is represented by &#9. A dot is represented by &#32. One &#8199 is a break between letters and two &#8199's are a space between words.

The morse code translates to:

> THE WISDOM YOU SEEK WAS YOURS ALL ALONG BUT ONLY IF YOU CAN EXPLAIN YOUR PATH HERE

Comment: Good work!  There were big bunches of white space but I didn't realize they were different characters. I'll have to check it when I get back to my PC.